# sufficient and necessary condition for equality between conditional mutual information and unconditional one.

Tags: information-theory

Suppose $X, Y, Z$ are three discrete random variables.

Is there a good sufficient and necessary condition for $I(X;Y|Z) = I(X;Y)$?

Usually the LHS can be bigger or smaller than the RHS, but if Z is constant, then they are equal. But this is a rather trivial observation.

**Motivation**

Conditional mutual information generalizes both (unconditional) mutual information and conditional entropy. For the latter point, one can make the following trivial observation and the relevant sufficient and necessary condition.

1. (trivial observation) $I(X;Y|Z) = H(X|Z)$ if knowing Y contributes
   large enough, to be precise, for example, if  X is a function of Y.
   Therefore conditional mutual information generalizes conditional
   entropy.
2. (sufficient and necessary condition) $I(X;Y|Z) = H(X|Z)$ if and only
   if X is a function of $(Y,Z)$.

For the former point, I can't seem to find any meaningful sufficient and necessary condition.

Comment: think of markov chains

Comment: @Euclean, I am not sure how Markov chain enters the picture when the condition $I(X;Y|Z)=I(X;Y)$ is invariant under permutation of the three variables, while Markov chain relation is not. And X,Y,Z forming a Markov chain only seems to imply $I(X;Y|Z) \le I(X;Y)$

Answer (score 1):

If $X$ and $Y$ are independent from $Z$, then  $I(X;Y|Z)=I(X;Y)$.

Comment: This would be a sufficient condition. The question is: is it necessary?